# How to disable virtual keyboard on GDM screen

Tags: fedora, x11, login, gdm

After an update to F28, every time I reboot my machine, the GDM screen is showing an ugly, unnecessary, and useless virtual keyboard instead of the login screen.

*How do I disable that?*

My login screen looks similar to this one:

[image]

The ugly virtual keyboard all over my screen.

Once I remove it, this is what I see:

[image]

That screen **does not** contain any accessibility options.

As as as I know, I installed Workstation ages ago (26, I think), updated to 27, and now to 28.

Comment: Did you try the accessibility options on the same screen?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There are no accessibility options on the same screen therefore I did not.

Comment: What do you mean by "There are no accessibility options"? They are in the [menu in the upper right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5a2s.png) of the login screen.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know where the options should be. They are **not** there. All I have is a reboot/shutdown icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on musings by [Michael Hampton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20805/michael-hampton), I tried to make sure that I was running `gdm` and not some other manager. I installed `system-switch-displaymanager` via

```
sudo dnf install -y system-switch-displaymanager
```

and ran `system-switch-displaymanager gdm`. Then, verified that it was running:

```
sudo systemctl status gdm.service                                            
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager                                          
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-22 14:16:48 BST; 4min 28s ago
 Main PID: 1341 (gdm)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 9.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           └─1341 /usr/sbin/gdm
```

I am now seeing what [this answer shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444662/10526) and no ugly on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

On screen keyboard driving you mad?

[image: Fedora login screen with on screen keyboard]

Get rid of it by clicking the accessibility icon in the upper right.

[image: Fedora accessibility menu], keyboard on]

You can then select "Off" for the keyboard.

[image: Fedora accessibility menu, keyboard off]

Comment: This is no what I see at all… First, the login screen looks like [this](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flinuxbsdos.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F12%2Ffedora-lxqt-login-615x460.png&f=1), the keyboard is full screen hiding the rest, and *there are no accessibility options*.

Comment: @Sardathrion You appear to have installed a Fedora spin (but not mentioned this important detail). In that case this answer is not going to help you. You may wish to edit your question further.

Comment: As far as I know, I am on Workstation…

Comment: @Sardathrion That's not Workstation, and that's not GDM. The image you posted is from Fedora LXQt spin.

Comment: Okay… The screen shot is not what I am seeing but is more what I am seeing that yours. This is an updated machine from 26 via 27 which was a workstation. I shall post an accurate screen shot tomorrow when I can access the machine in question. I am not meant to sound annoyed at you, I am just really annoyed at this change of behaviour for no damned good reasons whatsoever.

Comment: Update question with actual screen shots. Thanks for your patience, it is appreciated despite the sardonic tone of my comments… ☺

Comment: As a side note, what and how do I need to do to enable so my screen looks like yours?… I much prefer it to the stupid jelly fish picture… ☺

Comment: @Sardathrion OK, that _is_ the Fedora LXQt, not GDM.

Comment: Weird. I guess it got installed when I installed some QT application. Ah well. I am on gdm now in any case. Thank you.